# How fast do Iron Golems respawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create an Iron Golem trap as outlined in this wiki entry ([Iron Golem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)), however they seem to be respawning very slowly. I have enough villagers to spawn at least one golem, what else determines their spawn rate?

Answer (score 4):

The wiki states that they spawn near houses, and near 15 villages.

Increasing the number of villages will increase the maximum number of golems in your trap, so it will allow the game to try and make a spawn even if there is already a golem in the trap.

Houses are marked by doors, to adding more doors to the trap will increase the number of successful attempts to spawn.

You could also speed up the trap, so there are more spaces for golems to spawn.

Comment: That means, according to Ronan Forman, that the Iron Golems spawn rate is 1 per 350 seconds. They will only spawn, though, if they have the amount of space at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Spawn rate is 1/7000th per tick (20 ticks/second).  They spawn *very* slowly.